# Android Project Gitlab-ci.yml JAVA_HOME not set

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to create a .gitlab-ci.yml file in which an Android Studio project is automatically build. The file structure in my GIT repo looks like this:

```
the_app
.gitlab-ci.yml
README.md
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
image: jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android
variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "30"


before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - apt-get update -y && apt-get install wget -y  

build:
  script:
    - cd ./ISSD_application
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

But now I get the error that says:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

The Java installation that is used for the Android project is on my computer and not in the GIT-repo. How can I set the JAVA_HOME variable correctly so the project can build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `JAVA_HOME` is not set in the image but java binary is located under `/usr/bin/java`.

You can set `JAVA_HOME` in the same way you set `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, in `before_script` section :

```
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
  - apt-get update -y && apt-get install wget -y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Nicolas,
I get the following error after following your suggestion

Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
$ export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
$ apt-get update -y && apt-get install wget -y
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
$ echo "Compiling the code..."
Compiling the code...
$ chmod +x gradlew
$ ./gradlew build
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/bin/java
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```